# cannot install Ubuntu through ISO

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded a Ubuntu16 ISO file directly from the Ubuntu site, but when I set the virtual disk to install, it just does not run, just open the virtual disk and shows the folders on the boot cd. What do I perform the installation?

Comment: You perform the installation the same way you performed the Windows installation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Unetbootin to create a bootable USB. The rest is easy, just follow the on-screen instructions

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the **ISO** file and burn it to ether a **USB stick** or **DVD** the choice is yours,

You will to go into your **BIOS** and change the boot order so the device you desire will boot first.

After that you will need to boot from the **USB or DVD** and begin your installation...